# Promise `then` with a function returning nothing vs with a function returning an another promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I can't understand why we have such a strange result of execution this code.
Why isn't there an image of 12121212? And after each 1 we have three 2.

```js
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); })
.then(() => { console.log(1); return Promise.resolve(); });

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); })
.then(() => { console.log(2); });
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the fact that the `new Promise` has to be unwrapped first

Comment: The two promise chains are running asynchronously, it's unpredictable which order they'll each resolve.

Comment: They are all microtasks. And will resolve during the micro task phase. Just look up micro task to learn all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because there are multiple ticks involved in resolving the promise with another promise.

But really, you should ignore this, and never rely on timings between independent chains of promises.

Comment: Yes to: ***But really, you should ignore this, and never rely on timings between independent chains of promises.***

Comment: see also: [tasks vs microtasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth#Tasks_vs_microtasks)