# Order of processing microtasks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callstack, event-loop

I’m solving an event loop problem in Javascript and I can’t figure out why the output order is 2, 1, and not 1, 2.

```
f1();

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log(2);
});

async function f2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve();
  });
}

async function f1() {
  f2().then(() => {
    console.log(1);
  });
}
```

Let me tell you my reasoning:

1. As far as I understand, the first task in call stask will be f1. This function is asynchronous and returns a promise.
2. f1 is being executed.
3. Inside f1 there is a call to f2, which returns a promise and immediately resolves it. Therefore, a callback in "then" containing console.log(1) is added to the microtask queue.
4. There is one more task left on the call stack - Promise.resolve(). Here a callback in "then" containing console.log(2) also ends up in the microtask queue.
5. The call stack is empty, which means the event loop executes tasks from the microtask queue in order - 1, 2.

At some of these steps I was definitely mistaken in my reasoning. I will be very grateful if anyone helps me!)

Comment: Kind of irrelevant what you expect and what and why it really happens. You should *never* expect particular order of resolution of unconnected promise chains. If you need order, then connect the chains and work with that. If you don't expect an order, then you do not need to examine this. This is, at best, [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've simplified away all the relevant parts of the issue and are not asking for a workable solution.

Comment: Relevant: ["*you should ignore this, and never rely on timings between independent chains of promises.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761869)

Comment: The key point here is that the `Promise.resolve().then(...)` is a separate microtask from the one created by the `f2().then(...)` inside `f1()` the microtasks are executed in the order they are enqueued

Comment: Thanks for the answer) I just came across this problem during an interview, and unfortunately I couldn’t solve it correctly

Comment: Don't work for a company that asks this in an interview question.

Comment: The fact that `f2` is marked as `async` means it will wrap whatever its return value is in a Promise. So you have two microtasks from there.